# How to make Tomcat work with TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader defined in META-INF/context.xml together with WEB-INF/lib/spring-instrument-tomcat.jar

Tags: tomcat, classloader, spring-data, load-time-weaving, context.xml

I'd built a simple app which uses Spring Data 3.1.0.RELEASE and Eclipselink 2.4 on the server side - which is hosted in the Tomcat 7.0.27. In mywebapp/META-INF/context.xml I have Spring classloader

```
<Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
```

If I put `spring-instrument-tomcat.jar` into `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` then Tomcat runs mywebapp well but if I put `spring-instrument-tomcat.jar` into the `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/lib` - Tomcat dies with exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
```

Context loader parameter `useSystemClassLoaderAsParent` set to `false` does not help either.

I don't want to have any (custom) global lib in Tomcat (and it won't be easy to have the global one in our real-life production system) thus I'm trying to localize all the needed stuff in simple (yet big) war file. Any thoughts on how to achieve such encapsulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you do not want extra jars in Tomcat's lib folder, the only option (to still have Spring / AspectJ LTW work) is to edit the tomcat's run script to add -javaagent:...instrument.jar to its JAVA_OPTS or CATALINA_OPTS, and remove the context.xml file (you won't need TomcatInstrumentableClassLoad‌​er anymore).

Comment: I have to treat your answer as correct cause it's the best solution found so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be your `context.xml` is not right. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Context>
  <Loader
    loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"
    useSystemClassLoaderAsParent="false" />
</Context>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with **useSystemClassLoaderAsParent** but on Tomcat 7 I got `WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Loader} Setting property 'useSystemClassLoaderAsParent' to 'false' did not find a matching property.` And, as expected, the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader` was the next error.

Comment: I use tomcat7 also,but i successed.the spring-instrument-tomcat.jar should put into tomcat/lib.I don't think you put the right place.and i say,i use the intellij idea to develop,i put the context.xml in the tomcat7utf8\conf\Catalina\localhost\yourwebappnameDirectory\ here,and it completely like this:

`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="" docBase="your web app path">
  <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader" useSystemClassLoaderAsParent="false" />
</Context>
`
 web app not in the tomcat\webapp directory.

Comment: Ok, if I understood you correctly, you suggest to put tomcat-instrumental.jar in Tomcat/lib but this is exactly what I don't want to do (but I have no other ways to make it works for the moment. My question is how to leave Tomcat/lib untouched and satisfy my app with it's own libs.

Comment: ok,you dont want add anything to tomcat.the only way is that you should edit the tomcat.startup.bat to add the follow thing(that is spring suggest):
-javaagent:E:/spring-instrument.jar(may other place)
the spring-instrument.jar is not spring-instrument-tomcat.jar!

and leave context.xml nothing in it.and this way may work also.

yes,almost one thing you must do.may add some jar in tomcat or modify the startup script.

this is the way spring and aspectj suggest,i think you wont weave classes first only use aspectj,so this is the only way.